# Created Adview, now what?

Tags: java, android, adview

I created an adview, I check

```
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build(); 
            if(mAdView.getAdSize() != null || mAdView.getAdUnitId() != null)
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and it showed ads, but these are test ads from what I understand, how do I make it display real ads that I can earn from? I sent the app to my phone and it wont show ads, only when I created test device. How will the ads display on the view when I publish my app, do I need to use test device or am I missing something?

Comment: You change it from having it use a test device. There's plenty of info @Androind, in fact an exact tutorial how to do so. Don't do it until you release it though. For obvious reasons it can be frowned upon to write an app and let it earn money all day by your device. Of course this assumes you have an ad account and id.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils my app is finished, I just want to place ads and publish it, where is that tutorial?

Comment: Here's [one](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start). BTW, I think that `if` should be `&&`-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the ads display on your phone, add the code as below

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

You can read the [official document](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/eclipse) and don't worry. Once your apps published, the ads will work accordingly.

Comment: This is incorrect, it will display test ads, not real ones.